# Move forward not using unity Input system (while loop error)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to implement vertical movement in unity, but instead of using the `Input` system:

```
public float verticalInput;

void Update() {
  verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
  transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * verticalInput);
}
```

I tried to use `while` loop in the `Update`:

```
void Update() {
  while (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);

  }
}
```

But in this case, the game freezes, and I have to force-restart Unity.
If I replace `while` with `if` it works, but in this case, the character jumps forward ones, instead of moving continuously.

Why is it happening?

**UPD**
`GetKey` works with the `if` statement. Nevertheless would be interesting to know why the `while` loop didn't work and freeze the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, with the game freezing, is that `Update` is supposed to be called every frame, however in your `Update` function you've entered an infinite loop - on the frame you press W, `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))` will always be true, no matter how many times you call it, and so the loop never breaks, and Unity can never move onto the next frame

For reference, the reason `GetKey` works in the if statement but `GetKeyDown` moved the player only once, is because `GetKeyDown` returns true only on the frame where the key was pressed, while `GetKey` returns true on any frame where the key is held